# Blazor Reusable RenderFragments in code with event : Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

Anyone knows why the below doesn't work? If I remove "onclick" event then it compiles & works as expected. Is that we are not allowed to use event within [Reusable RenderFragments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-3.1#define-reusable-renderfragments-in-code)?

Env: ASP.NET Core 3.1 & Blazor Web Assembly

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

**Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type**

[image]

```html
@code {
    RenderFragment<(CategoryDto category, int myId)> rf =
      val => __builder =>
      {
        <h1 @onclick="()=> Console.WriteLine(val.category.Name)">Hello @val.category.Name, @val.myId</h1>
      };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @onclick handler in your code will ultimately be created by the EventCallbackFactory. However, that factory needs a reference to 'this' which isn't supported in field initializers - hence you are receiving this error (and probably another one regarding 'this').

The solution is pretty simple. You just need to turn the field into a property like so:

```
RenderFragment<(CategoryDto category, int myId)> rf => val => __builder =>
{
    <h1 @onclick="() => Console.WriteLine(val.category.Name)">Hello @val.category.Name, @val.myId</h1>
};
```

Comment: That worked. You probably wanna fix the typo "rf()" to "rf". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Notice than now it's not reusing rendering logic because you get new logic each time you use it. You don't get the extra performance.

Comment: @daniherrera I suppose what you could do is override OnInitialized() and then assign the RenderFragment there once.

Comment: Maybe a [getter](https://gist.github.com/ctrl-alt-d/fa3c4cbdeb27ee6e72d5d1507b332951)

Comment: @daniherrera can't I make it static so that it gives me the same instance all the time & I can still benefit from the performance? (Please note in the article I linked has the recommendation to make the RenderFragment static to be shared across multiple pages). Thank you!

Comment: So it's not really possible to share a RenderFragment across multiple files without creating a new instance every time?